# inner join дайте слишком много строк

Tags: php, mysql, sql, веб-программирование

есть 2 таблицы, изображений и товаров, изображений логично что больше, и вот мой запрос(ниже код) возращает столько строк сколько строк в таблице с изображениями, а мне надо чтобы выводило столько сколько в товарах

```
$query = "SELECT * from images INNER JOIN products ON products.id = images.uid";

                $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    echo '<a target="_blank" href="/pages/product-details.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="product-cart">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="product-image"><img src="/images/'.$row['url'].'" alt=""></div>
                                <div class="product-price-wrap">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="product-name">'.$row['product_name'].'</div>
                                        <div class="product-price">$ '.$row['price'].'</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </a>';

                        
                }
```

Comment: т.е. для каждого товара может существовать несколько изображений, но выбрать надо только одно? Тогда надо определиться с критерием выбора.

Answer (score 2):

Группировать не надо можно по другому, поскольку вы используете только
'id', 'url', 'product_name' и 'price', то можно переписать запрос иначе

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.id, url, product_name, price from images INNER JOIN products ON products.id = images.uid
```

но на случай когда у одного товара у вас много картинок тогда вам нужно определиться которую картинку вам нужно вернуть для одного продукта.

```
SELECT 
   products.id, 
   MAX(url), 
   product_name, 
   price 
FROM images 
INNER JOIN products 
  ON products.id = images.uid
GROUP BY
  products.id,        
  product_name, 
  price
```

Comment: спасибо буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете группировать выборку по `id` товара:

```
SELECT * from images INNER JOIN products ON products.id = images.uid GROUP BY products.id
```

Comment: Угу... и нарваться на ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.